# How do I enable speedbar to display all types of files?

Tags: emacs, emacs-speedbar

I have emacs v23.1.1 on ubuntu 9.10. i can't seem to make speedbar to display all files, it only displays directories. Does anyone have an idea with this?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Ok this might sound kind of basic but, have you right-clicked on the speedbar and checked 'Show all Files'? Otherwise, you should update the speedbar buffer by pressing 'g'.

There should be something like this on your emacs, though this is not usually set up by hand.

```
(custom-set-variables
 '(speedbar-show-unknown-files t)
)
```

Comment: Pfft who uses his mouse in Emacs? :P

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of keep info updated, in my updated emacs:
GNU Emacs 26.1 (build 1, x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.23.2) of 2018-08-13

To get .files continuing be showed, now I have to set

all-types-of-files
(custom-set-variables
 '(speedbar-show-unknown-files t)
)

**AND**

(setq speedbar-directory-unshown-regexp
      "^\(\.\.*$\)\'")

learned from:
https://emacs-devel.gnu.narkive.com/0k8PccN3/speedbar-and-dot-files